# Dynamically performing an action based on string passed in textfield

Tags: swift, closures

Say I have a textfield - `inputTextField`and a button on UI with action `performActionDynamically`, in same class I define two functions: 1. `firstFunc`, 2. `secondFunc`, now I want to achieve this behavior:

If user types "firstFunc" in textfield and then he taps on button it should invoke `firstFunc` function, and if he types "secondFunc" in textfield and then he taps on button it should invoke `secondFunc` function.

In objective-c I would have easily achieved it by following below pseudocode:

1. Within `performActionDynamically` pass `inputTextField.text` in `NSSelectorFromString()` to obtain selector
2. Invoke `performSelector:withObject:` on self to perform respective function

The only thing which I can think in implementing same behavior in swift is -

1. Define two closures with name `firstFunc`, `secondFunc`
2. Store the closures in a dictionary as values for keys - 'firstFunc' and 'secondFunc' respectively
3. Obtain respective closure from dictionary based on value in textfield
4. Invoke obtained closure

Is there any better way to achieve intended behavior? Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
if self.respondsToSelector(Selector(selectorString)) {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(0), target: self, selector: Selector(inputTextField.text), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

This is done as a callback, so you will have to take that into account.

---

You could use NSThread instead of NSTimer if you prefer:

```
NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(Selector(inputTextField.text), toTarget: self, withObject: nil)
```